# org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord.values() has default access

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

`org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord.values()` gives me the record values.
But, it is having default access specifier as of commons-csv-1.5.jar.

To get the values, I created a org.apache.commons.csv.MyCSVRecord class and delegated the call to CSVRecord.values() method using that. Its a hacky workaround.

Is there any existing accessor-class as part of org.apache.commons.csv ?
I don't understand why they have not exposed a public method to fetch values

Comment: What about using anyone of the overloaded `get()` methods, or using `iterator()`? Those are public